# FFMPEG fdk_aac Static Windows Builds

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder

I'm new in FFMPEG. I have download ffmpeg windows build but libfdk_aac is not enabled. Where I can get the ffmpeg build with complete encoder with libfdk enabled?

Comment: Take a look at the answer by MaPePer: http://superuser.com/questions/622349/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-libfdk-aac-in-64-bit-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't download a build of `ffmpeg` with support for libfdk_aac.

From FFmpeg's `LICENSE.md`:

> ### incompatible libraries
>
> The Fraunhofer AAC library (libfdk_aac), FAAC and aacplus are under licenses which
>   are incompatible with the GPLv2 and v3. We do not know for certain if
>   their licenses are compatible with the LGPL.
>
> If you wish to enable these libraries, pass `--enable-nonfree` to
>   configure. But note that if you enable any of these libraries the
>   resulting binary will be under a complex license mix that is more
>   restrictive than the LGPL and that may result in additional
>   obligations. **It is possible that these restrictions cause the
>   resulting binary to be unredistributeable**.

You will have to (cross)compile `ffmpeg` yourself. I have no experience compiling `ffmpeg` for Windows, but you could find more info about that at [Zeranoe FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Compilation Guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty old build (but it's an old question), but it still works allright: [FFmpeg Hi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-hi/)

> This is a static FFmpeg build including x264 (8/10 bit), x265 (8/10 bit), vp9 (8/10 bit) and fdk_aac (HE-AAC) especially for anime encoding.